# Print colored log messages

Tags: java, bukkit

I want to log a message (such as "Enabled!") with some color.
So far I have:

```
public void onEnabled() {
    // Here goes the method to say "Enabled!" colored
}
```

I have tried:

```
getLogger().info(ChatColor.GREEN + "Enabled!");
```

But it doesn't work: it shows as if I didn't add `ChatColor.GREEN`.

Comment: How can this plugin even load? The method is called `onEnable()` and should be annotated with `@Override`.

Comment: @Francesco Actually there's two methods, onEnable() and onEnabled() onEnable() runs when it's enabling and onEnabled() runs when the plugin has already been enabled.The Override annotation is recommend not required.

Comment: @L3n There is no `onEnabled()` method in [`JavaPlugin`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/plugin/java/JavaPlugin.html) class. Are you using a different server jar?

Comment: @Francesco weird..I often use onEnabled() and 1.7.2 version but other than that no I'm not using different jar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to send the message to the console sender:

```
Bukkit.getServer().getConsoleSender().sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Enabled!");
```

So it would be:

```
public void onEnabled() {
    Bukkit.getServer().getConsoleSender().sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Enabled!");
}
```